# How to prevent maven from loading broken dependencies into local repo at update

Tags: maven, dependencies, updates, local

There are many questions related to forcing maven to update local repo.
But after been downloaded, it's often happen somehow that broken files occur in place of expected fresh dependencies|files in local repo. They may look like partly downloaded files or error pages provided failed remote server, in my experience. Repeated attempts to refresh download dependencies may even broke more dependencies, including those, previously downloaded and putted in by hands.

There are separate application solutions to have a near guaranteed stock of already downloaded dependencies - Nexus, Artifactory, etc.

But is there a simpler solution of how to force maven verify downloaded artifacts before putting in local repo, via checksums provided to not pollute local repo?

Comment: First turn on checksum policy in your settings.xml and fail ... see more details https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2018/10/13/maven-artifact-checksums-what/

Comment: Thanks, khmarbaise! Seems like what I was looking for! Will try it out.